# How to prevent a Spacer to make a VStack greedly grow beyond necessary?

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui

I roughly have:

```
var body: some View
{
    HStack(alignment: .top) {

        AvatarView()

        MessageBubble()

        if message.isDeleted != true
        {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    // ...
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }
                Spacer() // THIS SPACER
                Button(action: {
                    // ...
                }) {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The root `HStack~'s height is dictated by the size`MessageBubble`which is always taller than its`AvatarView`and`VStack` siblings.

The problem is when I add a `Spacer` inside the `VStack`, then the whole `HStack` incredibly grows. The `Spacer` is "greedly" making everything grow with no limits.
I do want to have a button at the very top and the other at the very bottom of the `VStack` while being limited to `MessageBubble`'s height.

How could I make it grow no more than `MessageBubble`?

Comment: This is a Spacer feature - to consume all available space. Imaging it as a spring which shifts elements up to edge. Just don't use it and everything will be tighten by its content.

Comment: Just updated the question @Asperi.

Comment: Spacer().frame(minHeight: maxHeight) https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-fixed-size-spacer

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you expected something like this (elements alignment)

[image: subviews alighnment]

Here is demo code (frames for coloured rects are not important here, sizes just for demo, you will place your views instead there):

```
struct TestAlignmentSize: View {
    @State var height: CGFloat = 40
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                .alignmentGuide(.top, computeValue: { d in // [!!] 
                    self.height = d.height
                    return d[.top]
                })
            VStack {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Button")
                }
            }.frame(height: self.height) // [!!]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the height of the red rectangle to be dynamic (mainly text contents).